# Metabaseiis cannot write

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-6, iis-metabase

I try to modify the metabase of IIS6, I've cheched the checkbox to enable direct Metabase Edit.

I do my modification, I save and When I do iisreset my modifications are rollbacked.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct metabase updates will be overwritten by flushing pending in-memory changes to disk after an IISRESET, controlled shutdown or IIS just flushing a change whilst running.

IIS isn't clever enough to detect and merge changes that may have happened in memory with changes that may have been the result of a direct edit on `metabase.xml`.

If you really need to edit the metabase directly, stop IIS first, do your edit then restart, that's the sure-fire way to ensure direct edits will persist.

Did you know that the [`adsutil.vbs`](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true) script will allow you to modify pretty much any part of the metabase? This is a much safer and more reliable method than direct edits.